# How to use exact session name to enter a screen?

Tags: linux, shell, gnu-screen

I'm using screen to run a lot of different instances of an application and I name the the sessions "app1", "app2" etc.

The problem is that if I have a screen named "app10" started after the one named "app1", when I type

```
screen -r app1
```

I get attached to the app10 screen because it's the last screen created "matching" the name app1.

Is it possible to get rid of name matching and use exact names ?

For technical reasons I don't want to change app1 to app01. It's used in directory name, automation etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you rightly pointed out, screen uses the parameter value as a prefix.

A long alternative would be to type:

```
  screen -r $(basename /var/run/screen/S-$USER/*.app1}
```

(presuming that your sockets are in the /var/run/screen directory which is the default on Debian systems)

You can create an equivalent bash function in your `.bashrc` file

```
   function mscreen() {
      screen -r $(basename /var/run/screen/S-$USER/*$1)
   }
```

which let you type

```
 mscreen app1
```

to recover your session `app1` and not `app10`

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks a lot !
Here is the result : http://i.rems19.fr/6e629

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pid` prefix for that purpose:

```
man screen
```

> -r [pid.tty.host]
>          -r sessionowner/[pid.tty.host]
>               resumes  a detached screen session.  No other options (except combinations with -d/-D) may be specified, though an optional
>   prefix of [pid.]tty.host may
>               be needed to distinguish between multiple detached screen sessions.  The second form is used to connect to another user's screen
>   session which  runs  in
>               multiuser mode. This indicates that screen should look for sessions in another user's directory. This requires setuid-root.

Comment: Naming screen sessions is supposed to be a way of accessing them easier with a friendly name instead of the pid. Having to type screen -ls each time before accessing a screen is a bit annoying.

Comment: Agree, but you can create an alias for it

Comment: Do you mean something that will search for the pid using the screen name then enter the screen with the given pid ? That's quite interesting I'll look into it.